# Eclipse plugin: create a new file

Tags: eclipse, file, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to create a new file in an eclipse plugin. It's not necessarily a Java file, it can be an HTML file for example.

Right now I'm doing this:

```java
IProject project = ...;
IFile file = project.getFile("/somepath/somefilename"); // such as file.exists() == false
String contents = "Whatever";
InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes());
file.create(source, false, null);
```

The file gets created, but the problem is that it doesn't get recognized as any type; I can't open it in any internal editor. That's until I restart Eclipse (refresh or close then open the project doesn't help). After a restart, the file is perfectly usable and opens in the correct default editor for its type.

Is there any method I need to call to get the file outside of that "limbo" state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That [thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg39177.html) does mention the `createFile` call, but also refers to a `FileEditorInput` to open it:

> Instead of `java.io.File`, you should use `IFile.create(..)` or `IFile.createLink(..)`. You will need to get an `IFile` handle from the project using `IProject.getFile(..)` first, then create the file using that handle.
>   Once the file is created you can create `FileEditorInput` from it and use `IWorkbenchPage.openEditor(..)` to open the file in an editor.

Now, would that kind of method (from this [`AbstractExampleInstallerWizard`](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.common.ui/src/org/eclipse/emf/common/ui/wizard/AbstractExampleInstallerWizard.java?root=Modeling_Project&view=co)) be of any help in this case?

```java
  protected void openEditor(IFile file, String editorID) throws PartInitException
  {
    IEditorRegistry editorRegistry = getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry();
    if (editorID == null || editorRegistry.findEditor(editorID) == null)
    {
      editorID = getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry().getDefaultEditor(file.getFullPath().toString()).getId();
    }

    IWorkbenchPage page = getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    page.openEditor(new FileEditorInput(file), editorID, true, IWorkbenchPage.MATCH_ID);
  }
```

See also this [`SDOModelWizard`](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.emf/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.sdo/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.sdo.editor/src/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/sdo/presentation/SDOModelWizard.java?root=Modeling_Project&view=co) opening an editor on a new `IFile`:

```java
  // Open an editor on the new file.
  //
  try
  {
    page.openEditor
      (new FileEditorInput(modelFile),
       workbench.getEditorRegistry().getDefaultEditor(modelFile.getFullPath().toString()).getId());
  }
  catch (PartInitException exception)
  {
    MessageDialog.openError(workbenchWindow.getShell(), SDOEditorPlugin.INSTANCE.getString("_UI_OpenEditorError_label"), exception.getMessage());
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Indeed, opening the file in the correct editor did the trick. Thank you!