# Eclipse: how to refresh the current project programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm building an eclipse plugin in which I'm going to create a new file in my project.
Is there a way to refresh the current project?

I know that I can have a reference to all the project by calling

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()
```

And the iterate among them and use

```
IResource.refreshLocal()
```

However this approach is not the best one, especially if the user have a lot of projects.

An alternative would be explore the project for checking if the new file is present or not but I would avoid it.

Comment: It's not neccessary to call `refreshLocal` if you create the file with the workspace API, see `org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.create(InputStream, boolean, IProgressMonitor)`

Comment: @Tom Seidel Should I pass to that method `FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("myPath"))`?

Comment: dont't use 'java.io.File' when working with Resources in the Workspace. How to create a file, see the snippet in the question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624054/eclipse-plugin-create-a-new-file

Comment: @Tom Can you post it as an answer please? It worked and I would like to sign it as accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not neccessary to call `refreshLocal` if you create the file with the workspace API, see `org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile.create(InputStream, boolean, IProgressMonitor)`

How to create a file, see the snippet in the [Eclipse plugin: create a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624054/eclipse-plugin-create-a-new-file)

Answer (score 4):

It's a whole lot easier to refresh at the project level.

```
IProject project = root.getProject(currentProjectName);
project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
```

True, this might be inefficient, but you're sure that the whole project is refreshed.

Comment: Thank Gilbert, now the problem is: how can I retrieve the name of the current project? Thanks again!

Comment: @lucaghera: You already got all of the projects with the code in your question.  Eclipse isn't going to know which project is current.  That's up to you to determine.